# How can I test iOS & Android mobile applications using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: android, mobile, visualstudio, ios, android-automation

Here I have some test cases on Microsoft Test Manager (MTM), and those test case I have to execute on a real iPhone device but when I use Run & Record test of MTM to execute test cases its record my action on windows

Please help here to resolve this issue so that I can execute test cases on the real device, and use recording feature of the MTM tool.

Comment: Apart from utilizing a simulator of such a phone on Windows I'm afraid reading the test case, doing the steps manually is your only way out.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1: Microsoft Visual Studio App Center Test is a test automation service for native and hybrid mobile apps, also known as Test Cloud. Tests written using supported frameworks can be run with little modification on hundreds of unique device model and operating system configurations hosted in a Microsoft data center. Initiate test runs using the App Center Command Line Interface or the public REST API. App Center stores test results, including all associated media assets, for viewing at any time.

Test runs execute in a hosted fashion; upload the necessary assets (typically an app binary and test files) to Test Cloud to execute tests within our data center environment. Generated assets, such as screenshots and device logs, are retained for test report viewing.

Test Cloud does not currently support the following features:

- Manual testing
- Network condition simulation
- Cellular network connections
- VPN
- Load testing

Interact as users do

- Perform tap, double-tap, swipe, rotate, pan, long press, and pinch.
- Build custom gestures programmatically for advanced interactions.
- Query UI elements, app models, and even backend servers via public or private endpoints.
- Use CSS selectors to query interface elements in hybrid apps.

Use any device feature

- Change GPS location.
- Press physical buttons.
- Activate device camera.
- Rotate the device, switching between portrait and landscape modes.

Use tools you know and love

- Write tests in C#, Ruby with Cucumber, or Java with Appium.
- Use Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio for C# tests.
- Xamarin Test Cloud templates are integrated into Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio.
- Integrate with standard NUnit test runners.
- Share code for cross-platform tests between iOS and Android.

Analyze app performance

- See full-frame screenshots for every step of every test.
- Receive performance data (memory, CPU, duration, etc.).
- Compare reports against previous runs to find regressions and bottlenecks.

Test continuously

- Automatically kick off Xamarin Test Cloud runs from your nightly Visual Studio Team - - - Services build and get work items back in VSTS from Test Cloud so you know what to fix.
- Integrates with TFS, Jenkins, TeamCity, or any CI systems with custom post-build commands.

Xamarin.UITest is a testing framework that enables Automated UI Acceptance Tests written in NUnit to be run against iOS and Android applications. It integrates tightly with Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects but it can also be used with iOS and Android projects written natively in Objective-C/Swift and Java. Xamarin.UITest is the Automation Library that allows the NUnit tests to execute on Android and iOS devices. The tests interact with the user interface just as a user would, enter text, tapping buttons, and performing gestures – such as swipes. For more information on the components enable Xamarin.UITest to automate a mobile application

Read more about Xamarin.UITest @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/

Read more about App Center implementation @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/quickstarts/android/test

Option #2: With Microsoft's Xamarin Live Player, developers can link their iOS or Android phones with Visual Studio on Windows or Mac and then test the .Net mobile applications they’re building in a matter of seconds. There is no need to set up emulators or to use cables to deploy the code! To get started, download the Xamarin Live Player, pair it to Visual Studio, and deploy your code, and test the app.  The Xamarin Live Player is designed as a getting started sandbox for developers to get their ideas visualized on a device quickly. Since the source code is interpreted you may reach the limitations after some time and need to fully compile your app for device or emulator.

Xamarin.Forms Limitations

- Android 4.2 or later on ARM-v7a, ARM-v8a, ARM64-v8a, x86, or x86_64 processor.
- iOS 9.0 or later on ARM64 processor
- Custom Renderers are not supported.
- Effects are not supported.
- Custom Controls with Custom Bindable Properties are not supported.
- Embedded resources are not supported (ie. embedding images or other resources in a PCL).
- Third party MVVM frameworks are not supported (ie. Prism, Mvvm Cross, Mvvm Light, etc.).
- Live Player is not intended for native Android or iOS projects (that use Android XML or Storyboards for the user interface).
- Limited support for reflection (currently affects some popular NuGets, like SQLite and Json.NET). Other NuGets may still be supported.
- Some system classes cannot be overridden (for example, you cannot implement a subclass).
- Some platform features that require provisioning can't work in the Xamarin Live Player app (however it has been configured for common operations like photo gallery access).
- Custom targets and build steps are ignored. For example, tools like Fody, Refit, AutoFac, and AutoMapper cannot be incorporated.
- F # projects are not supported on Android and limited support on iOS
- Advanced scenarios with custom generic classes and interfaces may not be supported.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/player?tabs=android%2Cwindows

Option #3: Testing Mobile devices with Visual Studio using SeeTest plugin via https://web.archive.org/web/20150919162134/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/05/09/testing-mobile-devices-with-visual-studio-using-seetest-plugin.aspx

Some of the main advantages of SeeTestTM:

- Easy to use
- Record & play functionality that automatically generated C# code
- Plug& Play connectivity of the devices (via USB, WiFi or cloud configuration)
- Devices are as-is out of the retail store (NO JAILBREAK and NO ROOTING required)
- Low maintenance of tests due to Object identification by 4 methods that backup each other: Native ID, Image Recognition, Text Recognition (OCR), Web-DOM (HTML5)
- Fully integrative into Visual Studio with simple code export
- Supports ALL physical smartphones (all software versions, all physical models inc tablets)
- Supports ALL emulators
- Watch a video: https://vimeo.com/41248081
- Free trial download: http://experitest.com/download
- Online manual: http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/index.htm
- Free webinar including live demo: email support@experitest.com